# ValueError: No axis named userID for object type <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'

Tags: python, pandas

I want to count index elements by userID.My dataframe

```
       gender  adID  rating
userID                     
1           m   100      50
1           m   101     100
1           m   102       0
2           f   100      50
2           f   101     100
3           m   102      62
3           m   107      28
3           m   101      36
2           f   102      74
2           f   107     100
4           m   101      62
4           m   102      28
5           f   109      50
5           f   110     100
6           m   103      50
6           m   104     100
6           m   105       0
```

I tried

```
df.count('userID')
```

But got output

```
  File "/home/mm/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 5630, in count
    axis = self._get_axis_number(axis)
  File "/home/mm/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 357, in _get_axis_number
    .format(axis, type(self)))
ValueError: No axis named adID for object type <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

How to fix this?Do the index operations follow the same principles as the column ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `df.index`, but some pandas function are not implemented, so is possible use [`to_series`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.to_series.html) or `Series` contructor:

```
a = df.index.value_counts()
print (a)
2    4
6    3
3    3
1    3
5    2
4    2
Name: userID, dtype: int64

b = len(df.index)
print (b)
17

c = df.index.to_series().mode()
print (c)
0    2
dtype: int64
```